# How to remove floating point

Tags: bash

I have a variable as a string:

```
var="50.335"
```

I try to convert it to int like this:

```
var=$(printf "%.0f\n" "$((var))")
```

and echo it out:`echo $var`
But I get this error:

```
syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".335")
```

I need it to be an integer to be able to perform different operations with it. How can I convert it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing `printf "%.0f" "$(( 50.335 ))"` and `$(( ))` just accepts integers.

Just say:

```
$ var="50.335"
$ printf "%.0f\n" "$var"
50
```

---

From `man bash`:

> **Arithmetic Expansion**
>
> Arithmetic expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic expression
>   and the substitution of the  result. The  format for arithmetic
>   expansion is:
>
> ```
> $((expression))
> ```
>
> The  expression  is  treated as if it were within double quotes, but a
>   double quote inside the parentheses is not treated specially.  All
>   tokens in the expression undergo parameter  and  variable  expansion, 
>   command substitution, and  quote removal. The result is treated as the
>   arithmetic expression to be evaluated.  Arithmetic expansions may be
>   nested.
>
> The  evaluation  is performed according to the rules listed below
>   under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  If expression is invalid, bash prints a
>   message indicating failure and no substitution occurs.

And then:

> ARITHMETIC EVALUATION
>
> The shell allows arithmetic expressions to be evaluated, under certain
>   circumstances (...). **Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers**
>   with no check for overflow, though division by 0 is trapped and
>   flagged as an error.

---

Note you can also use [Shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to remove everything from the dot `.`:

```
$ var="50.335"
$ echo ${var%\.*}
50
```